# Factoring an ideal in a quotient polynomial ring

Tags: ideals, prime-factorization, polynomial-rings

I have been asked to show a number of facts about the quotient ring $\mathbb{F}_5[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3+1).$  One of the first things I'm asked to do is find the factorization of the ideal $(X-1)$ in this ring.  I'd love a hint as to how to go about this.

Comment: There's no $Y$ in ${\bf F}_5[X]$, so what does $Y^2-X^3+1$ mean?

Comment: That was a typo. Its meant to be $\mathbb{F}_5[X,Y].$